# Relationalize json deep nested array

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have following catalog and want to use AWS glue to flatten it

```
| accountId | resourceId | items                                                           |
|-----------|------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1         | r1         | {application:{component:[{name: "tool", version: "1.0"}, {name: "app", version: "1.0"}]}} |
| 1         | r2         | {application:{component:[{name: "tool", version: "2.0"}, {name: "app", version: "2.0"}]}} |
| 2         | r3         | {application:{component:[{name: "tool", version: "3.0"}, {name: "app", version: "3.0"}]}} |
```

Here is my schema

```
root
 |-- accountId: 
 |-- resourceId: 
 |-- PeriodId: 
 |-- items: 
 |    |-- application: 
 |    |    |-- component: array
```

I want to flatten it to following:

```
| accountId | resourceId | name | version |
|-----------|------------|------|---------|
| 1         | r1         | tool | 1.0     |
| 1         | r1         | app  | 1.0     |
| 1         | r2         | tool | 2.0     |
| 1         | r2         | app  | 2.0     |
| 2         | r3         | tool | 3.0     |
| 2         | r3         | app  | 3.0     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your schema and data, yours is a deeply nested structure, so you could `explode` on `items.application.component`, and then `select` your `name` and `version` columns from that.

*This link might help you understand:* https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/complex-nested-data.html

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("items", F.explode(F.col("items.application.component")))\
.select("accountId","resourceId","items.name","items.version").show()


    +---------+----------+----+-------+
    |accountId|resourceId|name|version|
    +---------+----------+----+-------+
    |        1|        r1|tool|    1.0|
    |        1|        r1| app|    1.0|
    |        1|        r2|tool|    2.0|
    |        1|        r2| app|    2.0|
    |        2|        r3|tool|    3.0|
    |        2|        r3| app|    3.0|
    +---------+----------+----+-------+
```